# Is such a function measurable in the product measure space?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_T,\mathcal{A},\nu)$ be a product measure space. Given a vector function $f:\Omega_T\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, we say that $f\in L^2(\Omega_T,\mathbb{R}^{m\times n})$ if $f$ is measurable with respect to $\nu$ and
    $$\int_{\Omega_T}\|f(t,\omega)\|^2d\nu<\infty.$$
Now $g(t,x(t,\omega))$ is a Caratheodory function (namely, for each fixd $x(t,\omega)\in\mathbb{R}^{mn}$, $ g(\cdot,x)$ is measurable, and for every $t\in[0,T]$, $ g(t,\cdot)$ is continuous) and $x(t,\omega)\in L^2(\Omega_T,\mathbb{R}^{m\times n})$. Is this function $g(t,x(t,\omega))$ measurable with respect to $\nu$?In addition, the function g also satisfies the following conditions
$$\exists h(t,\omega)\in L^2 :\|g(t,x(t,\omega)\|\leq h(t,\omega)+\|x(t,\omega)\|.$$
I want to prove that $g(t,x(t,\omega))$ is an $L^2-$function, then I should first prove that it is measurable，but I don't know how to verify that it is measurable。

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Which definition of Caratheodory function are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I have added  Caratheodory function definition.

Comment: Why do you denote the nonempty set as $\Omega _T $ instead of just $\Omega $ ?

Comment: $\Omega_T=\Omega\times T$. Here is a product measure space.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some hypothesis on $x(t,\omega)$. Assuming that $(t,\omega) \to x(t,\omega)$ is measurable you can prove this as follows: let $g_n(t,\omega)=g(t,\frac i {2^{n}})$ if $x(t,\omega) \in [\frac {i-1} {2^{n}},\frac i {2^{n}})$. Then each $g_n$ is measurable and $g_n\to g$ pointwise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The meaning is to add the hypothesis function $x(t,\omega)$  is measurable with respect to $\nu$， right?

Comment: Exactly. The process $(x(t,\omega))$ has to be a measurable process.

Comment: Yes! $x(t,\omega)$ is measurable and  is also $L^2$ function . Thank you very much!

Comment: Excuse me, I am sort of new to this topic. What are $t$ and $\omega $ ? And what kind of process are we talking about?

Comment: @evaristegd These notations come from theory of stochastic processes. $t$ varies over an interval $[0,T]$ and $\omega$ varies over a probability space $\Omega$.